# Android Sleep API Codelab on Watch: API is not supported yet

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to run the [Android Sleep API Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-sleep-api#0) ([source code on GitHub](https://github.com/android/codelab-android-sleep/)) to run directly on a Pixel Watch 2

Under Settings > System > About

> Wear OS by Google
> 4.0
>
> Model Google Pixel Watch 2

Under Settings > System > About > Versions

> Build number TWD9.240205.001.A
>
> Wear Core Services
> 1.8.1.561085711
>
> System UI
> 1.6.32.567711630
>
> Google Play Services
> 23.42.12 (240304-574052649)
>
> Android security patch March 5, 2024

I made only minor changes in the AndroidManifest.xml to run on the watch:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone" android:value="true" />
```

Following the instructions in the codelab, when running this code:

```
val task = ActivityRecognition.getClient(context).requestSleepSegmentUpdates(
   pendingIntent,
   // Registers for both SleepSegmentEvent and SleepClassifyEvent data.
   SleepSegmentRequest.getDefaultSleepSegmentRequest()
)

task.addOnSuccessListener {
   mainViewModel.updateSubscribedToSleepData(true)
   Log.d(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to sleep data.")
}
task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
   Log.d(TAG, "Exception when subscribing to sleep data: $exception")
}
```

The following exception is logged:

`Exception when subscribing to sleep data: java.lang.SecurityException: This API is not supported yet.`

What would cause the API not to be supported? The Fitbit app correctly records sleep data overnight